# Get message from chat via message_id?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I know how to get all the IDs from a chat via the received message (update.message.chat.id)

However I couldn't find a function in the docs of Pybot that allows to get a message with a specific ID from the chat (from the past).

Is there such a function available?

EDIT:
I found a function that should do what I want but it seems it is not available in Python-Telegram-Bot?
https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getMessages#
According to the note, it should be useable by bots as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between Telegram API and Telegram Bot API.
Link you provided is about Telegram API, and Bot API doesn't have method like that you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!
So I could use that function with my account via the API?
I guess I need an Token for that as well.
I also read something about a webhook?